# How do I implement a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How do I filter an array by a property that exists in another array?

I have this two arrays in my control:

```
this.items = [{ "Id": 1, "TypeId": 1, "name": "Michael" },
              { "Id": 2, "TypeId": 2, "name": "Helga" },
              { "Id": 3, "TypeId": 1, "name": "Max" },
              { "Id": 4, "TypeId": 2, "name": "Ann" }];

this.filterBy = [{ "Id": 1, "gender": "Male" },
                 { "Id": 2, "gender": "female" }];
```

And here is my ng-repeat in view template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list.items">
    <td>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center">{{ item.name }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the generated view:

[image]

At some point I want to filter items array by gender to show in the view above only females or only males.

I tried to implement filter, like this:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("sensorsData").filter('filterByGender', filterByGender);

    function filterByGender() {
        var result = [];
        return function (items, filterBy) {
            if (!items)
                return;
            if (!filterBy)
                return;

            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                angular.forEach(filterBy, function (f) {
                    if (item.TypeId == f.Id) {
                        result.push(item);
                    }
                })
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
})();
```

And here how I use it in view template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list.items | filterByGender:list.filterBy">
    <td>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center">{{ item.name }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The desired view in case if content of filterBy array like that:

```
this.filterBy = [{ "Id": 1, "gender": "Male" }];
```

The view Should display only items rows with TypeId = 1.

Like this:

[image]

But the filter above is not working.

And in the debugger I get this errors:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: r in list.arr | filterByAlert:list.filterBy, Duplicate key: object:8, Duplicate value: {"Id":1,"TypeId":1,"name":"Michael"}
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=r%20in%20list.arr%20%7C…%3A8&p2=%7B%22Id%22%3A1%2C%22TypeId%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22Michael%22%7D
    at angular.js:68
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:28799)
    at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:16734)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16869)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
    at done (angular.js:11454)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11652)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11593)
```

Why is the filter not working? And how can I create a filter to show items by gender?

And this:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:68
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16907)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
    at done (angular.js:11454)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11652)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11593)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13424
angular.js:17136 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

And this:

```
    Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Why is the filter not working? And how can I create a filter to show items by gender?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not filtering the list by `typeId`? Or that you've separated out what seems like relevant data into another variable?

Comment: @Jhecht , I need to filter data in generated view according to changes in filterBy array.

Comment: What do you mean by "the filter above not working"? What is the result? What did you expect?

Comment: @HugoWood I updated my question.

Comment: Could you provide examples of the expected output for some given input? For example, you don't mention what you expect your filter to output for the 2 input arrays you give at the beginning of your question.

Comment: @HugoWood ,  yes of course I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the `result` array in the wrong place.

```
function filterByGender() {
    var result = [];
    return function (items, filterBy) {
        ...
        return result;
    }
};
```

The `filterByGender` function here is what creates the filter function, while the anonymous inner function starting on line 3 is the actual filter function. Angular calls `filterByGender` only once, to build the filter, then calls the second function each time the inputs change. In your current code, the `result` array is always the same (i.e. only one exist in the lifetime of the application) and every time the filter is invoked, the items get pushed again into it. The filter then returns this array full of duplicates, and you get errors from Angular.

What you want instead is to get *new* results each time the inputs change, so `results` should be declared and initialized in the anonymous function, not `filterByGender`. Try this:

```
function filterByGender() {
    return function (items, filterBy) {
        var result = [];
        ...
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some very complicated filtering-with-functions-solution, but honoustly the easiest way in my opinion is to create a merged list of items that contains exactly what your view needs (i.e. a view model). This way, you can simply use `filter` on the `ng-repeat` to filter on gender.

Here's a code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  var items = [{ "Id": 1, "TypeId": 1, "name": "Michael" },
              { "Id": 2, "TypeId": 2, "name": "Helga" },
              { "Id": 3, "TypeId": 1, "name": "Max" },
              { "Id": 4, "TypeId": 2, "name": "Ann" }];


 $scope.types = [{ "Id": 1, "gender": "Male" },
                 { "Id": 2, "gender": "female" }];
  $scope.filterBy = $scope.types[0];

  var constructViewModel = function(items, types) {
    $scope.mergedItems = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(i){
      var mergedItem = angular.copy(i);
      var type = types.filter(function(t){return t.Id == i.TypeId})[0];
      mergedItem.gender = type.gender;
      $scope.mergedItems.push(mergedItem);
    });
  }
  
  constructViewModel(items, $scope.types);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <span>Filter by gender: </span><select ng-model="filterBy" ng-options="t as t.gender for t in types"></select>
  <div ng-repeat="item in mergedItems | filter: { gender: filterBy.gender } :true">
    <td>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center">{{ item.name }} {{item.gender}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </div>
</div>
```